# HOW to not move down a line in C after inputting number/character etc

Tags: c

header files i am using are *conio.h & *stdio.h

```
prf("ent two nos. \n");
scanf("%d",&n1);
printf("\t");
scanf("%d",&n2);
```

**REQUIRED OUTPUT**

> ent two nos.
>  2   10

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

> ent two nos.
>  2
>     10

Comment: try printing backspace character `'\b'`

Comment: Did you check deleting `printf("\t");`? And did you mean the output or the input? 
Because you can output it by using `printf("%d %d",n1,n2);`at the end.

Comment: It's not so easy to do that, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16814167/2675154) is a very similar question with several answers. Next time please use the search function first, before asking a question.

Comment: when i am inputting and press enter....the cursor moves to the next line...

Answer (score 0):

`2 10` is the input, not the output.

You have to read both numbers at once to have them in the same line:

```
printf("ent two nos.\n");
scanf("%d %d",&n1, n2);
```

Now you have to enter your numbers separated by a space and not by an enter.